# Haskell, how to return a list without encountering an error

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to wrap my head around Haskell with my first project where i have a function encountering an error:

> Exception: prelude.head: empty list.

```
selectNextGuess :: [[Card]] -> [Card]
selectNextGuess lst
    | length lst >= 1250 = lst !! (div (length lst) 2)
    | otherwise = newGuess 
        where fbList = [[feedback x y | x <- lst, y <- lst]]
              valuesList = [(calcValues(group $ sort[feedback y x | y <- lst, y /= x]), x) | x <- lst]
              (_, newGuess) = head(sort valuesList)
```

Any advice in steering me in the right direction to solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: the exception tells you that you called `head`  with an empty list - so your `valueList` was empty. If you did not call `selectNextGuess` with an empty list the problem is probably with your algorithm (maybe you can describe this here a bit) - can you change your algorithm to work with an empty list there? If yes you can pattern match on `valueList` for example

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR:* since a list can be empty, and there is *no* minimal element in the empty list, the way to return a list without the error is to *maybe* return a list, or rather to return a `Maybe` list.

---

If you call `selectNextGuess []`, `lst` inside the function `selectNextGuess` becomes `[]`. Then, `valuesList = [(calcValues(group $ sort[feedback y x | y <- lst, y /= x]), x) | x <- [] ] = []` is also an empty list. And then `(_, newGuess) = head (sort valuesList) = head (sort []) = head []` is called.

But there is no head element in the empty list. This is what the error message is telling us. You called `head` with `[]`, which is forbidden, because it has no answer.

The usual solution is to make this possibility explicit in the data type. We either have *just* *one* answer, for a non-empty list, or we have *nothing*:

```
data Maybe a =  Just a | Nothing
```

is such built-in type. So we can use it, and handle the empty `lst` explicitly:

```
selectNextGuess :: [[Card]] -> Maybe [Card]
selectNextGuess lst
    | length lst >= 1250 = Just $ lst !! (div (length lst) 2)
    | null lst = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just newGuess 
        where fbList = [[feedback x y | x <- lst, y <- lst]]
              valuesList = [(calcValues(group $ sort[feedback y x | y <- lst, y /= x]), x) 
                            | x <- lst]
              (_, newGuess) = head (sort valuesList)
```

Using `null` as a guard like that is a bit of an anti-pattern. We usually achieve the same goal with the explicit pattern in a separate clause, like

```
selectNextGuess :: [[Card]] -> Maybe [Card]
selectNextGuess [] = Nothing
selectNextGuess lst
    | length lst >= 1250 = Just $ lst !! (div (length lst) 2)
    | otherwise = Just newGuess 
        where ......
```

Using that `head ... sort ...` combination to find the minimal element is perfectly fine. Due to Haskell's lazy evaluation and the library `sort` being implemented as bottom-up *mergesort*, it will take *O(n)* time.

There is also a shorter way to write down the same thing,

```
....
    | otherwise = listToMaybe . map snd $ sort valuesList       -- or, 
                = listToMaybe [ x | (_, x) <- sort valuesList ]  --  whichever you prefer.
        where fbList = .....
              valuesList = .....
```

Since there is no more than one value "inside" a `Maybe _`,  the conversion function `listToMaybe` already takes just `head` element, implicitly.

Moreover, it produces `Nothing` automatically in the empty list `[]` case. So the explicit pattern clause can be removed, this way.